# SQL - Reduce the time request

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this table (eod) :

```
| eod_id | company_symbol |    date    | open  | close | high  |  low  | 
|      1 |            AAA | 01-01-2000 | 40.00 | 42.00 | 43.00 | 39.00 |
```

I use those 3 requests :

```
1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eod WHERE company_symbol="AAA" AND CLOSE>OPEN 
AND DATE BETWEEN "0000-00-00" AND "0000-00-00";
2. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eod WHERE company_symbol="AAA" AND CLOSE<OPEN 
AND DATE BETWEEN "0000-00-00" AND "0000-00-00";
3. SELECT min(date), max(date) FROM eod WHERE company_symbol="AAA"
```

Each request takes around 0,7sec to be executed, so I would like to reduce the time of each one. How could I process ? Is it possible to do the two first requests in only one ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Steve

Comment: What RDBMS are you actually using? If it allows you to build an index including computed colums such as `CASE WHEN CLOSE>OPEN THEN 0 WHEN CLOSE<OPEN THEN 1 END` that would allow the greatest optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suspect the first two queries can be combined:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN CLOSE < OPEN THEN 1 END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN CLOSE > OPEN THEN 1 END) 
FROM    eod
WHERE   company_symbol="AAA" 
AND     DATE BETWEEN "0000-00-00" AND "0000-00-00";
```

*(I assume you `DATE BETWEEN` clause is just an example, but if not it could be changed to `DATE = "0000-00-00"`)*

I'd say a nonclustered index on company_symbol is a must, if your dbms supports non key columns then include `OPEN`, `CLOSE` and `DATE` in this index, then depending on how frequently you insert/update data it may also be worth having indexes on your date columns too.

As always with performance based questions you are in a much better position to help yourself than we are to help you, you can view execution plans, IO statistics, and run various tests etc to determine what is slowing your query down, once you have identified the problem more specifically you can then look at adding specific indexes to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, it was just an example :) I'll try to add an index, but I'm a beginner in databases, so I don't have all notions.

Answer (score 1):

Combining first two:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN CLOSE>OPEN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Higher,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CLOSE<OPEN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Lower
FROM eod WHERE company_symbol="AAA"
AND DATE BETWEEN "0000-00-00" AND "0000-00-00";
```

Comment: Thanks, it reduce the time request by 2.

Answer (score -1):

My first suggestion to improve performance would be to never ever user **count(*)** but to use a single column like **count(eod_id)** in your case.

Comment: This is a myth in any sensible RDBMS.